# expected class-name before ‘{’ token C++

Tags: c++

I have a trouble with my c++ code. I know there is much advices with error "expected class-name before ‘{’ token" but I still can't find where I have it. Here is my sources:

```
Postava.h

#include <exception>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#ifndef __Postava_h__
#define __Postava_h__

#include "Barva.h"
#include "Pozice.h"
//#include "Budova.h"
//#include "HerniEngine.h"
#include "GrafickyObjekt.h"

class Budova;
class HerniEngine;
//class GrafickyObjekt;
class Postava;
struct Barva;
struct Pozice;

class Postava:public GrafickyObjekt{            //<----- Here is the error
private:
    std::string m_jmeno;
    int m_nosnost;
public:
    Postava(std::string jmeno, int nosnost);
    Budova* m_Budova;
    HerniEngine* m_HerniEngine;
    std::string vratJmeno();
    int vratNosnost();
    void vykresli();
};

#endif
```

GrafickyObjekt.h

```
#ifndef __GrafickyObjekt_h__
#define __GrafickyObjekt_h__

#include "HerniEngine.h"
#include "Pozice.h"
#include "Posun.h"

class HerniEngine;
class GrafickyObjekt;
class Scena;
struct Pozice;
struct Posun;
class HerniEngine;

class GrafickyObjekt {
protected:
    Pozice  m_pozice;
public:
    HerniEngine* m_HerniEngine;
    // kazdy potomek, tj. graf. obj. ma pozici
    GrafickyObjekt(Pozice pozice);
    // vsichni potomci ji musi implementovat
    virtual void vykresli() = 0;
    // tyto metody nejsou (ciste) virtualni, budou normalne zdedeny
    // tim mam zaruceno, ze vsichni potomci je maji
    void pohni(Posun posun);
    void pohni(Pozice pozice);
};

#endif
```

Sorry for my english and for names of classes and names of variables, it's in czech.

Thanks a lot for every advice.

Comment: Note that all identifiers containing two consecutive underscores are reserved for use by the C++ compiler and its standard library and you are not allowed to use them. The same applies for all identifiers startings with an underscore followed by a capital letter. This isn't your immediate problem, though. Your problem is that you have a cyclic dependency between your headers (as is the case for many of problems with the same error).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Same answer as in all similar questions asked before:

**You created a circular include sequence**

It is not obvious from what you posted so far (since you haven't posted all headers). But it is a safe bet that your other header files taken together must produce a circular include "path". More precisely, your `GrafickyObjekt.h` somehow indirectly includes `Postava.h` (through other header files that you haven't posted).

The include guards you used in your header files will "break" that cycle in some unpredictable or (better word) *unforeseen* way. In your case the include guards caused `Postava.h` to get physically included first, which is why it knows nothing about `GrafickyObjekt` even though it *seems* to explicitly include `GrafickyObjekt.h`. Hence the error.

Circular includes make no sense and achieve nothing. You have to stratify your headers by levels - from low level to high level -  and make sure that higher-level headers include lower-level headers, but never the other way around.

Once you achieve that sort of order, you can proceed to resolving circular data dependencies by introducing forward class declarations. I see that you already tried to do that and ended up with a total catastrophic mess, where you basically forward-declare all classes in all headers. Get rid of that mess and start over, by fixing the include stratification first.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me... I had Postava.h included in one other file that was included in GrafickyObjekt.h

Answer (score 1):

It seems that some of your previous includes are faulty.

```
#include "HerniEngine.h"
#include "Pozice.h"
#include "Posun.h"
```